# WordPress функция ajax не работает на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Нужно с ФронтЕнд отправлять данные для плагина методом AJAX. Для ПК браузеров работает но мобильные браузеры android chrome, ios safari - не отправляют данные.

Код который использую

ФронЕнд

```
function ajax_plugin() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: <?php echo wp_unslash( wp_json_encode( home_url() . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ) ) ) ?>,
            data: {
                action: 'event_plugin',
                plugin: 'QWERTY'
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        } )
}
```

БекЕнд

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_event_plugin', 'event_plugin' );

function event_plugin() {
    echo 'GOOD';
}
```

Comment: Да ладно. Код выглядит как совершенно рабочий, независимо от устройства. У вас до ajax скорее всего, дело не доходит. поставьте alert перед .stopPropagation

Comment: Первым делом ставил alert() в начало

Comment: А вторым делом - после stopPropagation? А что в dev tools->Network? куда идёт запрос, какой ответ?

Comment: Да, и самое смешное - на iphone небось пользователь не залогинен. И тогда да, конечно, код не работает. Потому что он не работает нигде для незалогиненного пользователя

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/hook/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action) попробуйте поменять хук на этот

Comment: @HTMLProgrammer надо не поменять, а добавить. 2 хука для 2х разных целей.

Comment: Да был не залогиненный, не знал про эти тонкости. Благодарен!